# Magento 2 custom ui_grid filterSearch issue

Tags: magento2, grid, ui-grid, fulltext

I have an error when attempting to search for a keyword in my custom table

[image: See error here]

In Network tab, i have a call to

> https://mylocalsite.local/admin/mui/index/render/?namespace=my_grid&search=123&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=po_date&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true

which returns

```
{"error":"UI component could not be rendered because of system exception","errorcode":"42"}
```

And in the exception.log i have:

> main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulltext' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `purchase_order` AS `main_table`
> INNER JOIN `admin_user` AS `u` ON u.user_id = `main_table`.created_by WHERE (((`fulltext` = 'abc')))

In my grid XML declaration i have the following:

```
...
<dataSource name="my_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Module\GridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">my_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
...

<listingToolbar>
    ...
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"></filterSearch>
    ...
</listingToolbar>
```

I have the database indexes in place (created from the install script)
[image: see full text indexes here]

However, when i try to search for something, i am getting that error i posted in the beginning of this question.
What am i missing?
Thank you.

Comment: you can open console window or network tab in developer tool of your browsers to see what exactly the error is. or try looking for errors in var/log folder

Comment: Hi Jimmy, i updated my answer with the errors from network tab and logs. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know why you have this, maybe you could try remove all the fields related to the error, in this case `fulltext`, try removing it, if the error went away, then we know the culprit, focus on that to see why it's wrong

Comment: I have no field called "fulltext", that must be from the <filterSearch name="fulltext"></filterSearch>, i don't have any other reference to "fulltext"

Comment: yup, try removing it. Then try with different functions in the grid such as sort, paging, filter with other fields other than text.

Comment: the other functions work well, except this search

Comment: Then I suggest you follow this tutorial https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/admin-grid.html

And then gradually make changes to fit your requirement.